# Why spin orbit coupling leads to band splitting?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, spin-orbit

For a crystal with time-reversal symmetry, its band structure is double degenerate. When we turn on SOC, the band splits except for special points where Kramers' theorem applies.

How should I understand this splitting correctly? I found that the SOC Hamiltonian is proportional to $\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}$ and energy is proportional to $\langle\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}\rangle=j(j+1)-l(l+1)-s(s+1)$. But this is the energy is for energy level splitting in atoms. How can I explain the splitting for the electronic band structure?.

Comment: A more general formula for spin-orbit coupling in a given potential is $\mathbf S \cdot (\mathbf p \times \mathbf E)$, where $\mathbf E$ is the electric field, $\mathbf p$ is the momentum and $\mathbf S$ is the spin. However in condensed matter systems this is much more complicated as it depends on the symmetries of the crystals, check the articles on [Rashba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashba_effect) and [Dresselhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dresselhaus_effect) effects.

Comment: Thanks! it helps a lot.